# Finding parameters in piecewise CDF

Tags: statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

The CDF of a continuous random variable X is:
$$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if } x < 4 \\
    Ax+B+\frac{C}{x} ,& \text{if } x \geq 4
\end{cases}
$$
(a) Find the parameters A, B, C.

Here is how I tried to solve the problem:

$\lim_{x \to \infty}F_x(x) = 1$

{${A = 0, B = 1}$}

Then for the calulation of C my instinct says to just say that $F_X$ is continuous however we have been taught that $F_X$ is only "right" continuous, which does not help me because I can't say:
$\lim_{x \to 4^-} = F_X(4)$ and from there find the value of C.

Comment: Your CDF seems to be over defined on $[2,4)$

Comment: @Henry sorry for that. I fixed it now

Comment: It must be $F_x(\infty ) - F_x(4) = 1$, so i found $C=-4$

Comment: @MetehanTuran Thank you for your input but I can't see why that should be the case. I think by doing that you just imply that $F_X$ is continuous because you are basically saying that $lim_{x \to 4^-} = F_X(4) = 0$. I'm wondering whether the  the continuity of $F_X$ can be guranteed from the fact that the random variable is continuous.

Comment: I thought that derivative of F gives the PDF ( probabilty density function). Let it be "f". If you integrate $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x)dx$  you must get $1$. (comes from probability axioms). Integral of f is F. So $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x)dx = F(\infty ) - F(-\infty )=1$ . we know that for only x>4, F is grater then 1. Thus we can say $F(\infty ) - F(4) =1$

Comment: @MetehanTuran regarding your logic i still can't get why $lim_{x \to -\infty}F_X(x)=lim_{x \to 4^-}F_X(x) =F_X(4)$. I think that would be the case if $F_X$ would be continuous. Anyways i think i got my answer from Henry. Thank you

Comment: Hi, it is not about continuity. We have $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x)dx = 1$. We can split the integral where we desire, $\int_{-\infty }^{4 } f(x)dx + \int_{4}^{\infty } f(x)dx = 1$. Now left hand side integral must be zero according to CDF. So $\int_{4}^{\infty } f(x)dx = 1$. Then $F(\infty ) - F(4) =1$.

Comment: @MetehanTuran Wait this actually makes sense. Sorry for not getting it earlier. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $F_X(x)$ to be weakly increasing and, with $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}F_X(x) =0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}F_X(x) =1$, never exceeding $1$ or being below $0$.

Your instinct to say that $F_X(x)$ is continuous is wrong in general (it is [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)) but correct for a continuous random variable. So here you will need the CDF to be continuous everywhere, in particular at $4$.  So indeed $\lim\limits_{x \to 4^-}F_X(x) = F_X(4)$.

Having found $A=0,B=1$, that will make $C=-4$, and so $F_X(x)=1-\frac{4}{x}$ on $x \ge 4$. This will be weakly increasing and have the correct limit of $1$ on the right.

You can go further and say that the density is
$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if } x < 4 \\
    \frac{4}{x^2} ,& \text{if } x \geq 4
\end{cases}
$$

and that you have a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with shape parameter $\alpha=2$ and minimum $4$.

Comment: so does a continuous random variable always have a continuous CDF?

Comment: Yes - that is what makes it "[continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Continuous_random_variable)".  Similarly an "absolutely continuous random variable" has an absolutely continuous CDF (and this then allows you to find a density)

Comment: Thank you very much this was really helpful